# GWT show weather

Tags: gwt, weather

I want to show the weather in my GWT application.  I have seen several examples of this done on the server side which seem a little odd to me because obviously moving the load to the client is preferred.

I researched the matter quite some time now and could not find an answer. 
Can this be done on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason people do it server-side is to avoid cross site requests.  Weather Underground however provides a JSONP capable service API, so I would use that to implement it client-side.

http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/documentation.html

http://eggsylife.co.uk/2010/04/22/gwt-2-jsonp-and-javascript-overlays-with-jsonprequestbuilder/